# Random variable $X$ has uniform distribution on section $[0,2]$. What's the expected value of variable $Y=\frac{X^{4}}{2}$

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Random variable $X$ has uniform distribution on section $[0,2]$. What's the expected value of variable $Y=\frac{X^{4}}{2}$

I don't know how to start this task.
I know formula for density of this distribution:

$f(x))\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{b-a} &,x\in [a,b] \\ 
0 & ,x\notin [a,b]\ 
\end{matrix}\right.$

If I put values from section I will get:

$f(x))\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{2} &,x\in [0,2] \\ 
0 & ,x\notin [0,2]\ 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Can I use this to solve this task or should I take a go at it with different method?

Comment: Do you know how to determine the expected value of a (function of a) random variable, from a PDF?  For instance, if you wanted to find the expected value of $X$, you would write $E(X) = \int_{x=0}^2 x f(x)\, dx$.  If you want to find the expected value of $Y$, you would write $E(Y) = \int_{x=0}^2 y(x) f(x) \, dx$, where $y(x) = \ldots$?

Comment: Do you have a definition for expected value (given a continuous random variable and probability density function)?

Comment: @BrianTung so $y(x)=\frac{x^{4}}{2}$, what should I do about $f(x)$?
$f(x)=\frac{x^{1}}{2}$ based on density?

Comment: Answer would be $\frac{{8}}{5}$ in this case, is this right?

Comment: You already have $f(x)$ in your problem statement.  Only look at the interval $[0, 2]$.  ETA: Incidentally, the usual term for a closed interval is a **segment**.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician

Comment: @BrianTung Are you sure $8/5$ is not correct? I got the same result, and I also numerically checked it.

Comment: @VarunVejalla: You're right.  That's what I get for doing it in my head.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a shortcut somewhere, so you can find $\mathbf{E}Y$ without the pdf, but I don't know it. So first, it's the easiest to find CDF of $Y$:
$$
P(Y<y) = P(X^4<2y) = P(0<X<(2y)^{\frac{1}{4}})
$$
Since $X$ is positive, and $X^4$ is a strictly increasing funciton, it's easy enough to find it. From that, take a derivative to get pdf. Now, follow @BrianTung's suggestion by using the definition of $\mathbf{E}X$

Answer (score 1):

The expected value of a probability distribution, $g(x)$, is defined as $\int_{\mathbb{R}}x g(x) dx$. In your case, $g(x)$ is the distribution of $\frac{X^4}{2}$, where $X \in U(0, 2)$. Using the substitution $x = \frac{u^4}{2}$, which is equivalent to the [law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician), the integral becomes  $$\int_{0}^{2} \frac{u^4}{2} \cdot\frac{1}{2-0} \  \mathrm d u$$

Can you finish from here?